# Text disappears according to number of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a group of images toggling class when clicking. There´s a text line at the bottom.

This text disappears according to the number of characters.
I´m unable to find the reason.

On the snippet, when clicking on an image:

- The blue box has more than 22 characters and the text is ok.
- The green box has less than 22 characters and the text disappears .

```js
$('.photo').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expandImage')
});
```

```css
p.text {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 1.35rem;
  line-height: 0;
  color: #c2c;
  display: block
}

p a {
  font-size: 0.65rem;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

img.photo {
  height: 49%;
  width: 49%;
  cursor: zoom-in;
  /*cursor:url(file:///Macintosh HD/Desk/PENDIENTES/FOTOS/GENERAL/zoom.cur), -moz-zoom-in;*/
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

img.photo.expandImage {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 97.8%;
  height: 97.8%;
  cursor: zoom-out;
}

.container {
  box-shadow: 0.075rem 0 0 0 #C9C9C9, 0 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9, 0.075rem 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9, 0.075rem 0 0 0 #C9C9C9 inset, 0 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9 inset;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  max-width: 25rem;
  max-height: 25rem;
  min-width: 20rem;
  min-height: 20rem;
  padding: 0.32rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1rem 3% 4rem;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3.25rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  right: 0;
  color: #FF0004;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0387/1545/products/product_analysis_1024x1024.png?v=1426535435);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img class="photo" src="http://letsprattle.com/image/prattle-icon-square-white.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://letsprattle.com/image/prattle-icon-square-white.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://letsprattle.com/image/prattle-icon-square-white.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://letsprattle.com/image/prattle-icon-square-white.png" alt="" title="">
  <p class="text">Text<span style="color:#2E27A8"> – With 22 charact</span></p>
  <a class="info" href="#">info</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img class="photo" src="http://www.northperthcommunityhospice.org/images/icons/calendar-icon.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://www.northperthcommunityhospice.org/images/icons/calendar-icon.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://www.northperthcommunityhospice.org/images/icons/calendar-icon.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://www.northperthcommunityhospice.org/images/icons/calendar-icon.png" alt="" title="">
  <p class="text">Text<span style="color:#2E27A8"> – With 21 charac</span></p>
  <a class="info" href="#">info</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any change or any problem. Does the text `Text - With 21 charac` change on your computer when clicking on an image?

Comment: yes, disappears. Same on Codepen: https://codepen.io/danielillo/pen/YYxqoE , tested on Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Comment: I did not see any change. WHat is The issue show me

Comment: @Daniel Same on Codepen, no visible change or issue for me (using chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (32-bit)). Problem with your computer/old versions?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIgJ4qt1U44&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `width: 100%;` and `flex-shrink: 0;` to `p.text` which prevents this element from moving up into the empty space behind the absolutely positioned large image and hiding behind the image (i.e. being covered by it):

(Applying `position: absolute` to one of the images also creates whitespace in the lower right since into which the text moves if you don't force it to have full width.)

```js
$('.photo').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expandImage')
});
```

```css
p.text {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 1.35rem;
  color: #c2c;
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

p a {
  font-size: 0.65rem;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

img.photo {
  height: 49%;
  width: 49%;
  cursor: zoom-in;
  /*cursor:url(file:///Macintosh HD/Desk/PENDIENTES/FOTOS/GENERAL/zoom.cur), -moz-zoom-in;*/
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

img.photo.expandImage {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 97.8%;
  height: 97.8%;
  cursor: zoom-out;
}

.container {
  box-shadow: 0.075rem 0 0 0 #C9C9C9, 0 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9, 0.075rem 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9, 0.075rem 0 0 0 #C9C9C9 inset, 0 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9 inset;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  max-width: 25rem;
  max-height: 25rem;
  min-width: 20rem;
  min-height: 20rem;
  padding: 0.32rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1rem 3% 4rem;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3.25rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  right: 0;
  color: #FF0004;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0387/1545/products/product_analysis_1024x1024.png?v=1426535435);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img class="photo" src="http://letsprattle.com/image/prattle-icon-square-white.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://letsprattle.com/image/prattle-icon-square-white.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://letsprattle.com/image/prattle-icon-square-white.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://letsprattle.com/image/prattle-icon-square-white.png" alt="" title="">
  <p class="text">Text<span style="color:#2E27A8"> – With 22 charact</span></p>
  <a class="info" href="#">info</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img class="photo" src="http://www.northperthcommunityhospice.org/images/icons/calendar-icon.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://www.northperthcommunityhospice.org/images/icons/calendar-icon.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://www.northperthcommunityhospice.org/images/icons/calendar-icon.png" alt="" title="">
  <img class="photo" src="http://www.northperthcommunityhospice.org/images/icons/calendar-icon.png" alt="" title="">
  <p class="text">Text<span style="color:#2E27A8"> – With 21 charac</span></p>
  <a class="info" href="#">info</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, but i need a while to understand the reason. Thanks.